# Error when deploy to heroku: Could not detect rake tasks remote: ! ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

```
Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     Don't know how to build task 'assets:clobber' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
remote:  !     Did you mean?  assets:clean
```

Comment: "ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app"—so, can you? What happens if you run `bundle exec rake -P` on your development machine?

Comment: bundle exec rake -P
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'assets:clobber' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
Did you mean?  assets:clean